# getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) - any context?

Tags: android, multithreading, sharedpreferences, android-context

[I have a helper class](https://github.com/Utumno/AndroidHelpers/blob/master/src/gr/uoa/di/android/helpers/AccessPreferences.java) for dealing with the default shared preferences. I retrieve the preferences once and I wrap all the SP methods I need, providing the same cached instance. It goes like:

```
public final class AccessPreferences {

    private static SharedPreferences prefs; // cache

    private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context ctx) {
        // synchronized is really needed or volatile is all I need (visibility)
        SharedPreferences result = prefs;
        if (result == null)
            synchronized (AccessPreferences.class) {
                result = prefs;
                if (result == null) {
                    result = prefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
                }
            }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean contains(Context ctx, String key) {
            if (key == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("Null keys are not permitted");
            return getPrefs(ctx).contains(key);
    }
    //etc
}
```

I have two questions I want to be absolutely sure about:

- Do I need synchronization as I do or a simple volatile would suffice ? Of course this helper class is accessed by different threads (the UI, Intent services etc).
- Do I need to call `ctx.getApplicationContext()` or not when retrieving the shared preferences ?

I am interested in Froyo and up

Answer (score 0):

Use synchronization, but I would suggest using something like a ReentrantLock (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) instead of "synchronized". It is generally more performant.

Any context will work, so long as it's not null of course. I would just use the application context here, which will save your callers from having to supply it. Expose a static reference to it, as seen here: [Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

Comment: "Use synchronization" -> why not just volatile ? "Any context will work" -> will a reference to it not be held upon ? Positive ? Btw extending application is frowned upon - and this is in a library - my callers _will_ have to provide me a context

Comment: If you are going to use a the "Double-checked locking" approach to a singleton, yes, use the volatile and synchronization. There is a good example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking. Better yet, why not go with the latest accepted approach, using an Enum? This too allows for lazy-loading type access and is thread safe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_Enum_way I don't think extending the app. is frowned upon (references?). you can still get the app context: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext().

Comment: Also, if you're going to hold onto any Context reference... it SHOULD be the Application context. Any other Context could lead to a memory leak (images, etc) that, trust me, you don't want to deal with. In other words, I'd rather have a reference to a non-visual Context like the app context, than one with who knows how many references that are likely UI elements.

Comment: Another example where the ApplicationContext is preferred over, say, an Activity. Written by Romain Guy himself: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: There is no singleton here, nor could it be and the enum pattern (which I use extensively) has no place. I do use double check but I wonder if it can be _replaced_ by volatile, as I think it is clear. I am not holding into any context of course as you can see - I don't know what the SP are doing - that's what I ask. For your reference search for "Hackborn" and "extend application". Please try to answer the question not other questions that I did not ask, and know the answers to :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I think I did answer the question, quite concisely. Cheers buddy, just trying to help. What you are doing isn't that complicated. You sound quite confident and pompous in your responses, yet you are struggling to solve a simple issue. Perhaps Google will help you. Good luck, pal.