# does it guarantee to give same result in getDefaultSharedPreferences within Context?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20850829/361100) but still have a question.

If I use `getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())` and `getDefaultSharedPreferences(SomeActivity.this)`, does it gurantee to give same result (same xml preference file access)?

Comment: Exactly, that "discussion" leaves something to be wanted. The answers here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wishing you a happy new year-2014

Both will behave same !!

View.getContext(): Returns the context the view is currently running in. Usually the currently active Activity.

Activity.getApplicationContext(): Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside of). Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the current Activity.

ContextWrapper.getBaseContext(): If you need access to a Context from within another context, you use a ContextWrapper. The Context referred to from inside that ContextWrapper is accessed via getBaseContext().

Please Note that behind the scenes

```
getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

calls

```
getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE)
```

as far as I understand: Context is the Base Object. So every Activity same as Application derives from Context. This means that every Activity and every Application IS a Context;
Hope now you understand the things so we can say that they will produce same behave.

Please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html 
and
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 1):

yes it does. The context parameter  is used to get the package name, that will be used as name for the xml file in which android stores your values. You can see the androis's source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java#PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29)